# It is required to write a query that returns, for two dates, the total balances of active deals on these dates in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following table is given:

Columns

1. Deal start date
2. Deal end date
3. Amount

There is a table:

| Start Date | End Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 01.01.2021 | 1 |
| 15.04.2020 | 15.04.2021 | 3 |

It is required to write a query that returns, for two dates, the total balances of active deals on these dates.

It is required to display balances on date 1 = 02.05.2020 and date 2 = 02.02.2021

I know how to get them one by one

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) 
FROM Table
WHERE 02.05.2020 >= End Date
```

Or

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) 
FROM Table
WHERE 02.05.2020 >= End Date OR 02.02.2021 >= End Date
```

But I have no idea how to create a separate table for dates:

```
date 1 || amount 1
date 2 || amount 2
```

Can you give me some advice or direction for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation or filtered sum function as the following:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN '02.05.2020' >= End_Date THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Date1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN '02.05.2020' >= End_Date OR '02.02.2021' >= End_Date THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Date2
FROM table_name
```

Or:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Amount) FILTER (WHERE '02.05.2020' >= End_Date) AS Date1,
  SUM(Amount) FILTER (WHERE '02.05.2020' >= End_Date OR '02.02.2021' >= End_Date) AS Date2
FROM table_name
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iVroffbn).

Comment: Thank you! 

I want to ask additional question. Do sql have a way to transpose result table?

Comment: You are welcome,  do you mean transopose like this https://dbfiddle.uk/r2uK9IUa